# Is there a Vim like "Command Line Window" for Bash?

Tags: bash, vim, vi-mode

Is there something similar to Vim's "Command Line Window" for Bash where I can see/edit/execute items from the history?

In Vim when I press `:` and then `Ctrl-F` it opens the window that shows the entire command history:

```
7. Command-line window              *cmdline-window* *cmdwin*
                            *command-line-window*
In the command-line window the command line can be edited just like editing
text in any window.  It is a special kind of window, because you cannot leave
it in a normal way.

OPEN                        *c_CTRL-F* *q:* *q/* *q?*

[..]

When the window opens it is filled with the command-line history.  The last
line contains the command as typed so far.  The left column will show a
character that indicates the type of command-line being edited, see
|cmdwin-char|.
```

When you press `Enter` the current line is executed.

(I know that I can search the history with `Ctrl-R`, `/` (vi-mode), etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two alternatives.

Either you can install `hstr` (https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) which features a suggest box with advanced search options to easily view, navigate, search, and manage your command history:

[image]

Otherwise, Bash features a vi-like command line history editor. Do a `set -o vi`, then you can search throughout history via these keystrokes:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> enters command mode

<kbd>/</kbd> begins a search; type search string, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform a search.

<kbd>n</kbd> goes to next match, while <kbd>N</kbd> goes to the previous match

<kbd>i</kbd> goes back to insert mode

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the mentioned hstr, [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) (fuzzy finder) is an interactive filter for drilling down into lists, not just shell history (a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut for that is provided out of the box), but also more files, hostnames, and so on. There are multiple search modes (fuzzy or literal), too.